# Ajax - I want to return an error if the variable did not return anything

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

My code returns a rating if .find() is successful and a data exists. I want to return an error if there is no data on itemname found. If the file nameOfBusiness=Cafe, then it will return the rating 3 but if I had nameOfBusiness=Restaurant then it should return an error "Rating not published yet."

A data form my xml:

```
<resultitem>
   <itemname>Cafe</itemname>
   <rating>3</rating>
</resultitem>
```

I have the ajax code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'someUrl.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml){
        var rating = "";                                
        $(xml).find('resultitem itemname:contains("'+nameOfBusiness+'")').each(function(){
        rating = $(this).parent().find('rating').text()
                if(rating==""){
                    alert("Rating is not published yet.");
                } else {
                    alert(rating);
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'someUrl.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml){
        var rating = "";                                
        var found = $(xml).find('resultitem itemname:contains("'+nameOfBusiness+'")');

        if (!found.length) { //HERE
            alert('error');
            return;
        }

        found.each(function(){
            rating = $(this).parent().find('rating').text();
            if(rating==""){
                alert("Rating is not published yet.");
            } else {
                alert(rating);
            }

        });
    }
});
```